# Where did QEMU come from in my Startup Disk Creator?

Tags: usb, live-usb, virtualization

Yesterday I was playing with **Startup Disk Creator** in Ubuntu 16.04.

After doing a Live install to USB, I noticed a "**Test Disk**" button.

[image: test disk button]

I never noticed this button before so I pressed it.

A QEMU window opened, loading the OS from the newly made Live thumb drive.

[image: QEMU]

There was no need to reboot.

Great feature I thought, just like MultiBootUSB has.

I tried to duplicate the install, booting from the new thumb drive.

No luck, the Test Disk button was gone.

**My question**

How did/do I add this "Test Disk" feature to Startup Disk Creator on a new install.

**Bonus Question**

How would I add this feature to mkusb?

I recall having installed MultiBootUSB and QEMU previously on the computer, but I have not been able to duplicate the merging of QEMU and SDC since.

Comment: Maybe installing MultiBootUSB (and QEMU) did the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried installing MultiBootUSB 9.2.0 and found that QEMU no longer comes with the tool, you need to download it yourself.

I tried installing several versions of QEMU, qemu-system, qemu-kvm,

What finally worked was:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm qemu virt-manager virt-viewer libvirt-bin
```

My Startup Disk Creator now shows the "Test Disk" button.

For now I guess I will just have to run QEMU manually when working with mkusb, unless @sudodus comes up with something.